# Refrigerator Water Line Connector

Tags: refrigerator

I currently have a PCV water line to my fridge.

[image]

I’d like to connect a braided line to it to connect to the fridge. Is there a connector that will do this? I’m trying not to replace the entire line to my basement.

Comment: Can you provide a picture of the water line?  Why are you interested in doing this?

Comment: So you'd like to connect a braided line to the fridge and what are you going to connect the other side of that braided line to? Post a picture of what you want to connect to and someone will let you know what fitting/adapter to use and how to do it. PVC comes in different sizes so a picture is really needed.

Comment: It’s a normal 1/4 pcv line with a female connector. I tried connecting directly to the fridge and it has a slow leak and I was afraid to tighten more. The delivery guys said I need a braided line because I can’t over tighten a braided line.

Comment: That's probably a polyethylene line. I'm going to assume it uses compression fittings. Usually people don't use the inserts on the compression fittings and they leak. If that's what it uses you can simply remove the nut that you've been tightening and the polyethylene line and replace with the braided line. You can over tighten a braided line.

Comment: This is why it was requested that you provide a picture. There are a _lot_ of eagle-eyed people 'round here who can help identify installation errors and tell you how to fix them, even when _you_ haven't a clue that it was done wrong.

Comment: I suspect your existing line and fitting will work fine but that you did not tighten it **enough**. Compression fittings need to be *tight* or they will leak.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you're in the US that line should be 1/4". For the braided line you want 1/4" compression x 1/4" compression. It will have a fitting at each end with a rubber washer built in and it will connect directly to the fitting on the fridge. The other end of that line in the photo will have the same fitting.

Google  "1/4" icemaker braided line"

Comment: (Squinting) it seems like the brass tube insert piece is missing from that compression fitting? If so, get one at plumbing drpt. and install in tubing. The braided tubing is typically only available in certain short lengths, like 5 feet. What distance will you need?